# ClassFactory automatic added to ClassTypeFactory

Tags: c++, templates

I got three classes. One `ClassFactoryBase` which looks like this:

```
class ClassFactoryBase {
public:
    virtual ~ClassFactoryBase () = default;
    virtual AbstractBase* Create() = 0;
};
```

I inherit from that class the actual Factory as a template

```
template <typename Type>
class ClassFactory final : public ClassFactoryBase {

    ClassFactory (/*ClassFactoryBase& Factory*/); //Idea to automatically add them
    ~ClassFactory () = default;
    AbstractBase* Create() override; //returns new Type

};
```

And ofc I implemented the Factory itself:

```
class ClassTypeFactory {
public:

    template<typename Type>
    void AddFactory(ClassFactoryBase& ClassFactory); // inserts ClassFactory into the map m_Factories

    AbstractBase* Create(const std::string& ClassType);
private:
    std::map<std::string, ClassFactoryBase&> m_Factories;
};
```

If I implement it like this I have to add to this Inside of my main.cpp

```
ClassTypeFactory class_type_factory;
ClassFactory<TopClass> top_state_factory(&class_type_factory);
class_type_factory.AddFactory<TopClass>(top_class_factory); // leave this out
```

This works just fine but I wonder if I could implement it in a way that I can leave out the last line. I think it should work because they both use the same template parameter. 
I tried to give my ClassFactory a reference to a Factory and than call the `AddFactory` Method in there but I cant make it work. I always get inaccessible errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do it in correct order. Following modified version of your example (using smart pointer):

```
// Your objects to create:
struct AbstractBase
{
    virtual ~AbstractBase () = default;
    // ...
};

struct Derived : AbstractBase
{
    // ...
};

// Your abstract factory
class ClassFactoryBase {
public:
    virtual ~ClassFactoryBase () = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> Create() = 0;
};

// Your factory collection    
class ClassTypeFactory {
public:

    void AddFactory(const std::string& name, ClassFactoryBase& factory) { m_Factories.emplace(name, std::ref(factory)); }

    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> Create(const std::string& name)
    {
        return m_Factories.at(name).get().Create();
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<ClassFactoryBase>> m_Factories;
};

// Your real factory
template <typename Type>
class ClassFactory final : public ClassFactoryBase {
public:
    ClassFactory(const std::string& name, ClassTypeFactory& factory) { factory.AddFactory(name, *this); }
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> Create() override { return std::make_unique<Type>(); }
};
```

And then usage:

```
ClassTypeFactory class_type_factory;
ClassFactory<Derived> top_state_factory("TopClass", class_type_factory);

auto ptr = class_type_factory.Create("TopClass");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51bc7026a71a0952)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer but my compiler doesnt like this either. I still use normal Pointers but that should not be a problem.... Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  "ClassFactory<Class>::StateFactory(ClassTypeFactory &factory) [with Class=Waiting]" (declared at line 45 of "c:\Users\z0041spv\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Bachelorarbeit\Bachelorarbeit\ClassFactory.h") is inaccessible

Comment: *"[..] is inaccessible"*: check accesses so: `public` (or `protected`/`friend`).

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much... I really forgot that public inside the ClassFactory... This cant be true.

Comment: Hello again. I tried to use smart pointers aswell now and I cant access the Create() Method inside the factory collection. I can only access the member Methods of the AbastractBase. `return m_Factories.at(name).get().Create();`

Comment: @HWilmer: Can you provide MCVE with your problem? As my demo works.